# Setting a form value with Javascript - what is wrong with this?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
forminfo = document.forms[0];
forminfo.direction.value = 'back';
alert('going '+forminfo.direction.value);
```

Output is an alert box with the message "going undefined". Is there something wrong with the way I'm setting the value? Thanks!

Here's the html:

```
<form action='/cgi/CIRF/CIRF-new.pl' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='direction' value='forward' />
```

The form is defined multiple times throughout the perl script. Each has a 'direction' value set, and only one form is ever output on the page at a time.

Edit: sorry, should have included the top line of the javascript where forminfo is defined.

Comment: Are you sure `forminfo.direction` is actually an element?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the option to add form's name attribute you may do the following:

```
<script>
    x = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    //we suppose that the first form of the document
    alert('going '+x[0].direction.value);
 </script>
```

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/35gAm/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the perl script was outputting the form twice! Sorry guys, didn't realise until I actually viewed source in the browser. All good now :)

Answer (score 0):

try this `<input type='hidden' name='direction' value='forward' onclick='javascript:window.history.go(-1)' />`